# React native - Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent

Tags: android, react-native, androidsdk31

I am developong a react native project which is using `react-native: 0.63.3` and I was using SDK 30. But as in google play console it is requested minimum of SDK 31 I have updated it. Everythin in the code was running fine. But I don't receive andy notification and incoming call/ out going calls & notifications. And I [image]

I tried every solutions in the google. I have added `implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0-alpha05'` in my gradle file and also added `android:exported="true"` in the manifest file. But non of them work.

Also I tried to update the modules as

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
    notifyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        getApplication(),
        REQUEST_CODE,
        notifyIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
    )
} else {
  notifyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        getApplication(),
        REQUEST_CODE,
        notifyIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )
}
```

But that crashes my whole application. Is there a possible way to fix this issues? Also I don't want to update my react native version. Please help.